# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.editvehicle}:

Tags: android

Unable to start activity

> ComponentInfo{com.example.android/com.example.android.editvehicle}:
>   .lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   -'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

Not able to get edit text value from one activity to anohter.

```
public class editvehicle extends Activity {


    public static String NAMESPACE="http://tempuri.org/";
    static String URL=MainActivity.URL;

    public static String METHOD_NAME="updatevehicle";
    public static String SOAP_ACTION="http://tempuri.org/updatevehicle";


    public static  String id;

    ArrayList<String> listarray = new ArrayList<String>();
    EditText e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7;
    Button b1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.editvehicle);

        e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editvehiclenoet);
        e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editvehicletypeet);
        e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editrcnoet);
        e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpucet);
        e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpucpicet);
        e7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editinsuranceet);

       b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.edituservehiclebutn);

        e2.setText(addvehicle.e2.getText().toString());
        e3.setText(addvehicle.e3.getText().toString());
        e4.setText(addvehicle.e4.getText().toString());
        e5.setText(addvehicle.e5.getText().toString());
        e6.setText(addvehicle.e6.getText().toString());
        e7.setText(addvehicle.e7.getText().toString());
       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {


               new updatevehicle().execute();
           }
       });

    }
    public class updatevehicle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(editvehicle.this);
            dialog.setTitle("Loading");
            dialog.setMessage("Please Wait ..");
            dialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try
            {
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
               //request.addProperty("id",listarray.get(posi).split("-")[0].trim());
                //request.setProperty(e2.setText(););
                request.addProperty("id",id.split("-")[0].trim());
                request.addProperty("username",MainActivity.username);
                request.addProperty("vehicle_no", addvehicle.e2.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("vehicle_type", addvehicle.e3.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("rc_no", addvehicle.e4.getText().toString());
                request.addProperty("puc", addvehicle.e5.getText().toString());   
                request.addProperty("puc   _pic", addvehicle.e6.getText().toString());    
                  request.addProperty("insure_file",     addvehicle.e7.getText().toString());

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet=true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

                SoapPrimitive resultstr = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();

                Log.d("message","Message : "+resultstr.toString());
                return resultstr.toString();


            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ERROR", e.toString());
                return e.getMessage();

            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(editvehicle.this, "Vehicle Added", 1).show();
            String[] col = result.split("-");          // rows split by ,
            listarray.clear();
            for(int i =0;i<col.length;i++)
            {
                //String col[]= rows[i].split("-");
                //Buses bus = new Buses(col[1],col[2],col[3],col[4],col[5],col[6]);
                //Buse.add(bus);
                //listarray.clear();
                //listarray.add(col[0]);
               /* e2.setText(col[2]);
                e3.setText(col[3]);
                e4.setText(col[4]);
                e5.setText(col[5]);
                e6.setText(col[6]);
                e7.setText(col[7]);
                */listarray.add(col[i]);
                //listarray.add(col[2]);    //add in array           represent the each rows
                //listarray.add(col[1]);

                //listarray.add(col[2]);
                //listarray.add(col[3]);
                //listarray.add(col[4]);
                //listarray.add(col[5]);
                //listarray.add(col[6]);
            }
            finish();


        }

    }
}
```

Comment: too old question

Comment: what is "addvehicle" ?

Comment: atleast ans if its too old for u

Comment: its activity @GaneshPatil

Comment: Search on google `How to pass values using Intent in android`

Comment: you are accessing edit text value from another activity by activity name ?

Comment: yes@GaneshPatil

Comment: why don't you not try to set value in intent or bundle and pass it to second activity

Comment: i have tried to pass in bundle but didnt got the output

Comment: what you tried please post

Comment: e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editvehiclenoet);
e3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editvehicletypeet);
e4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editrcnoet);
 e5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpucet); e6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editpucpicet);
 e7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editinsuranceet);
e2.setText(addvehicle.e2.getText().toString());
e3.setText(addvehicle.e3.getText().toString());
e4.setText(addvehicle.e4.getText().toString());
e5.setText(addvehicle.e5.getText().toString());
e6.setText(addvehicle.e6.getText().toString());
e7.setText(addvehicle.e7.getText().toString());

Comment: I think your setting null or empty value in this line  - e2.setText(addvehicle.e2.getText().toString());